# Black lines on ipad safari, but not on desktop safari

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, browser, safari

I'm using this slideshow:

http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/

Which results in black lines where the image is being "sliced" (see the demo above). What would cause this kind of behavior?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried posting in the comments section? It seems pretty active, you might get a better answer there straight from the dev or people that know about that plugin.

Comment: I'm not seeing the lines on my iPhone 4S.